# Replace the exact sentence from the paragraph in R

Tags: python, html, r, regex, string

I am trying to match the sentence from a paragraph and replace them.

Below is the Dataframe -

```
fulltext = c(rep("<span style=\"font-family:Calibri\"><span style=\"font-size:18px\">__ - Now</span>\r\n\r\n<strong><span style=\"font-size:24px\">X - Soon</span></strong>\r\n\r\n<span style=\"font-size:18px\">__ - N</span></span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri\"><span style=\"font-size:18px\">ext Scheduled Maintenance or Inspection</span></span>",3),
  "<span style=\"font-size:20px\"><strong><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif\">What is Triggering this Expert Alert?</span></strong></span>")

cleantext = c("__ - Now", "X - Soon", "ext Scheduled Maintenance or Inspection", "What is Triggering this Expert Alert?")

replacetext = c("__ - Nu", "X - Binnenkort", "ext Gepland onderhoud of inspectie", "Wat veroorzaakt deze expertwaarschuwing?")
data5 = data.frame(fulltext, cleantext, replacetext)
```

This is what I am trying to do -

1. Take the sentence from cleantext
2. Match with fulltext
3. replace cleantext with replacetext in fulltext

For example.  <span style=\"font-size:20px\"><strong><sp an style=\"font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif\" >***What is Triggering this daert Alert?***</ span></strong></ span>

Above is the complete paragraph, I want to replace the sentence in bold with ***Wat veroorzaakt deze expertwaarschuwing?***

Output Should look - 
<span style=\"font-size:20px\"><strong><sp an style=\"font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif\" >***Wat veroorzaakt deze expertwaarschuwing?***</ span></strong></ span>

This is what I have tried so far. Now I have tried a couple of ways to do it.

1. using string replace
2. tried adding ^ and $ to the start and end of the sentence, then use gsub to match that as regex pattern. But I think that works only with words. Below is my try, but it did not work.

`data5$cleantext2 = paste0("^",data5$cleantext,"$")
gsub(data1$Cleantext2[1], data1$replacetext[1], data1$fulltext[1])`

Comment: The `^` and `$` will foil your attempts, as there appears to be something both before and after it. You might try word-boundaries instead, perhaps `paste0("\\b", data5$cleantext, "\\b")`.

Comment: BTW: `gsub` is only going to work on one pattern as a time; if you need to do it across the whole frame, perhaps `mapply(gsub, data1$Clean2, data1$dutch, data1$en_us)`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to apply gsub using mapply. it doesnt work the way I want to. I will try the paste0 solution now.

Comment: Is this an iterative application? That is, replacing all instances of `cleantext` from each individual `fullttext`?

Comment: Yes I will be running on a loop. select each row and replacing them

Comment: @r2evans adding \\b doesnt work -  `paste0("\\b", data5$cleantext, "\\b") `

Comment: Is there a reason you've tagged this with [tag:python]? It's clear your language so far is R, so if you are amenable to a solution in python as well then you should explicitly state that, otherwise it appears that you are using extra tags to get extra viewers (which ... I don't know, is that a problem? is it counter or just strategic? \*shrug\*)

Comment: Oh I thought it would be a regular expression solution. I am building the app in R and Python both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No loop necessary. Also, your `^` and `$` are not going to work since your replacement patterns are mid-string. You can mitigate mis-matches with fixed patterns.

Since you want to apply all patterns/replacements to each of `fulltext` (not just a 1-for-1), then I think you can `Reduce` it.

```r
Reduce(function(s, ptn) gsub(ptn[1], ptn[2], s, fixed = TRUE), 
       Map(c, cleantext, replacetext),
       init = fulltext)
# [1] "<span style=\"font-family:Calibri\"><span style=\"font-size:18px\">__ - Nu</span>\r\n\r\n<strong><span style=\"font-size:24px\">X - Binnenkort</span></strong>\r\n\r\n<span style=\"font-size:18px\">__ - N</span></span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri\"><span style=\"font-size:18px\">ext Gepland onderhoud of inspectie</span></span>"
# [2] "<span style=\"font-family:Calibri\"><span style=\"font-size:18px\">__ - Nu</span>\r\n\r\n<strong><span style=\"font-size:24px\">X - Binnenkort</span></strong>\r\n\r\n<span style=\"font-size:18px\">__ - N</span></span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri\"><span style=\"font-size:18px\">ext Gepland onderhoud of inspectie</span></span>"
# [3] "<span style=\"font-family:Calibri\"><span style=\"font-size:18px\">__ - Nu</span>\r\n\r\n<strong><span style=\"font-size:24px\">X - Binnenkort</span></strong>\r\n\r\n<span style=\"font-size:18px\">__ - N</span></span><span style=\"font-family:Calibri\"><span style=\"font-size:18px\">ext Gepland onderhoud of inspectie</span></span>"
# [4] "<span style=\"font-size:20px\"><strong><span style=\"font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif\">Wat veroorzaakt deze expertwaarschuwing?</span></strong></span>"
```